# Can I integrate Datanitro into an executable?

Tags: python, excel, datanitro

I'm looking to be able to create an executable with py2exe or something similar that takes information from an excel sheet and returns a word file.

Since my coworkers are technically challenged, I need to create an executable that will take the work out of it for them.

Two questions here:

1. I have to be able to import something into the python script that represents DataNitro. What module represents DataNitro?
2. Is this legal? I won't be using a DataNitro license on every machine this exe will run on, besides my own, so if it's even possible, is this a bit shady?

Thank you.

P.S. If I'm not able to do this I will probably have to use xlrd,xlwt,etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to give non-technical users access to DataNitro is to copy the VBA interface: hook the script up to an Excel button and have users press that button to run it. (There's no difference between running a Python script with DataNitro and running VBA code from the user's point of view.)

Each person using the script would need a DataNitro license.

There's no way to make DataNitro work with py2exe, unfortunately.

Source: I'm one of the DataNitro developers.